# Number of residue classes in the Gaussian integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $z$ be a Gaussian integer. It is known that the number of residue classes modulo $z$ is precisely $N(z)$. Wikipedia has a geometric proof of this fact; can someone point me to a purely algebraic proof?

Comment: It's Theorem 7.14 in Keith Conrad's note on $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which you can find here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf

Comment: Thanks! This works, though I was actually looking for a different proof (based on explicitly computing remainders using the division algorithm), so references to additional proofs are still welcome.

Comment: Since you ask for a "purely algebraic proof", note that this is a general property, not restricted to the Gaussian ring : if A is the ring of integers of a number field  and z is a non zero element of A, then $\mid N(z) \mid=$ card $(A/Az)$. See any textbook, e.g. Samuel's ANT, chap.3, §3.5.